# Alexa is unable to connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, eclipse, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to connect alexa with my website. I created an Alexa skill (following the guide) that works in connecting with a website like "numbersapi" it asks the user for a number and reads the answer given by the site. This is the code:

```
function httpGet(query) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

var options = {
    host: 'numbersapi.com',
    path: '/' + encodeURIComponent(query),
    method: 'GET',
};  

var req = http.request(options, res => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    var responseString = "";

    //accept incoming data asynchronously
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        responseString = responseString + chunk;
    });

    //return the data when streaming is complete
    res.on('end', () => {
        resolve(responseString);
    });
    res.on('error',(error) => {
        reject(error);
    });
});
req.end();
```

});
}

And the Intent:

```
const questionIntentHandler = {
canHandle(handlerInput) {
     return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
        && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'questionIntent';
    },
handle(handlerInput) {
    const theNumber = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.info.value;
    var query = parseInt(theNumber);
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        httpGet(query).then((response) => {
            resolve(handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(response)
            .withShouldEndSession(false)
            .getResponse());
            }).catch ((error) => {
                resolve(handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak('Request error').getResponse());
            });
    });
},
```

};

It works perfectly.Now I'm trying to use it for my very simple website but I can't get it to work. I created a simple form in a jsp that sends a number and opens another jsp page where a string is displayed based on the number. Changing the number to display in the url works, but when I try to apply the number through alexa it doesn't work. I think I have problems with the options.

```
 var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    path:  '/SearchFact?info=' + encodeURIComponent(query),
    method: 'GET',
};
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The problem is that your website is on localhost, so Alexa can't access it. You have to put your website live on the internet.

Comment: @rivamarco Thank you. I created a simple web api and published it, but alexa still can't get an answer. Can it be a certificate problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the API works? And what kind of error do you obtain with Alexa?

Comment: You should put a `console.log(error)` statement in your `.catch()` handler function to see the actual error response.

Comment: I solved. The problem was that the return value was not a Json.